# How to get page generation time in MODx Revolution?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

MODx placeholder for page generation time in Evolution was `[^t^]` and it was described on rtfm.modx page.

I just read whole page about Revo placeholders, search in rtfm and google for 'page generation time' and didn't find such placeholders.

I have tryed

```
q: [[^qt]] ([[^q]]) + php: [[^p]] = [[^t]]
```

(as described in one's blog) inside my #footer chunk and get no results.

Who knows how to get page generation time in MODx Revo? Is there still placeholder or I have to write my own snippet for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the syntax looks like Evo, the tags [^qt^], [^q^], [^p^] and [^t^] **do** work in Revolution.

However the way Revo works means that the Query Time and Request tags are often unreliable - http://forums.modx.com/index.php?topic=56800.0

Try out the [Executioner](http://www.jasoncoward.com/technology/2010/10/the-executioner-snippet.html) wrapper snippet to check how long individual snippets take to execute.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
Query Time: [^qt^]
Request: [^q^]
PHP Exec: [^p^]
Total time: [^t^]
```

Comment: Try install demo template of modx, that code of snippet is they use.

Comment: 22 hours ago that code gived me empty strings. Next time, 12 hours ago it works. 26s for php, 0 for sql. I have to use Executioner now to understand the situation. Thank you.